# What is this funny word?

Tags: riddle, word

> I'm a funny word really,
>   Even though I can mean the difference between life and death
>   In me you'll find the acquirement of goods
>   And also the beginning of something additional
>   Even a great snake, having eaten you and your questions
>   Preceding a great city, although a bit scrambled
>   What word am I ?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

A bit of a stretch, maybe, but are you by any chance

> Buoyancy? (at least I find that word a bit funny)

Life and death can definitely depend on it, if you are in danger of

> drowning

Acquirement of goods can be found

> **bu**o**y**ancy

as can the beginning of something additional

> buoy**an**cy (beginning of ”and”)

The snake is a

> **b**u**o**y**a**ncy (boa)

and it has clearly eaten both ”you” and the question ”why”, as those can be seen inside it, and the scrambled city is

> New York City, or ”NYC” -> ”ncy”

Comment: Brilliant answer, this looks like it to me. +1.

Comment: Pretty sure that's it. Nice riddle and nice answer!

Comment: You got it! I had another word in mind for "the beginning of something additional" (with the first 3 letters, or 4 phonetically at least), but yours works too.

Comment: Maybe I should add an ancillary comment to the answer so we can all see the original idea too?

Comment: Maybe indeed...